# Updating to App Engine Java 11 Standard Environment: Project Facets in Eclipse

Tags: java, google-plugin-eclipse

I wanted to check out the App Engine Java 11 Standard Environment and tried to switch my project to Java 11. But in the Project Facets, I can only choose JRE7 or JRE8.

Can I do something other than wait for an update of the Google cloud tools for eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CT4E does not yet support Java 11. Work is underway to support Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

There are no plans to extend Cloud Tools for Eclipse with support for Java 11/17 App Engine. [[1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/3710)]

Plugin maintainers are recommending using [Maven](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/using-maven)/[Gradle](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/tools/migrate-gradle) plugins instead, and reading [Java 11/17 migration documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/migration-center/standard/migrate-to-second-gen/java-differences).

Note that IntelliJ plugin won't be updated either. [[2](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/create-standard)][[3](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2665)]